# Subdomain doesn't show images from root Domain (Drupal)

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7, subdomain, plesk

I have a site up and running using Drupal.I use a web-hosting service, that uses Plesk 12 panel.Recently I decided to add a subdomain for the mobile version of my site.So I created a subdomain inside Plesk, pointed it to www.mydomain.com and named it m.mydomain.com.My desktop site is in httpdocs folder and my mobile version in m.mydomain.com folder.Then I added redirection to my mobile site when a mobile device is detected.

The problem is that m.mydomain.com does not show images because they are uploaded in httpdocs/sites/default/files which is my desktop site.Is there a way to access that folder from my subdomain?I have no access to http config files.Is there a way to do this from .htaccess file of my sub-domain?

*UPDATE
My structure is:

root
-----httpdocs
----------desktop site folder
-----------------desktop site files
----------mobile site folder
-----------------mobile site files
----------images

Comment: Are both of these websites Drupal installations?

Comment: yes...the mobile version is mostly copy paste, except some php files i modified to look better on mobile screen.

Comment: Question then, instead of using a mobile subdomain, m.mydomain.com, why not build a responsive Drupal theme and just have one domain with one site?

Comment: One other question: do the websites use the same database, or separate?

Comment: They use the same database.The main reason I chose subdomains is because I want a different layout in my mobile version.Different layout, same content.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this? Please help

Answer (score 0):

The best option I can think of is to use the Drupal module [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain).

From the module's page:

> The Domain Access project is a suite of modules that provide tools for running a group of affiliated sites from one Drupal installation and a single shared database.

Using that, you should be able to apply a different theme to the subdomain site than what you are doing with your main domain. You could use JavaScript or the like to redirect people to the subdomain.

The second option is that there is already a module called [Mobile Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_tools) that allow you to change theme and other settings for mobile devices. The description for that module page is as follows:

> The Mobile Tools module provides Drupal developers with some tools to assist in making adjustments to your site based on the visitor's device.

It was mentioned in this question, "[How to redirect users to mobile site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32884/how-to-redirect-a-user-to-mobile-site)". However, I must caution you against using the Mobile Tools module as it is only in development, and the last contribution to it was 3 years ago. (Plus they have a big warning on their module page that says "Do not use on production".)

Either of these modules should be able to get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, but I just can't figure out how to configure domain access...it says something about server settings and i don't have access to server files.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a redirect, I would place the images in a folder accessible to both systems. My understanding is right now you have something similar to...

site1/images
site2

If you move your images folder higher in your folder architecture to the same level as site1 and site2 and you update your Public file system path and Private file system path in the media configuration to be that directory it will resolve your issues. Essentially your folders will end up looking like this.

site1/
site2/
images/

Comment: This seems to be reasonable, but if i create a image folder in root folder, my sites will not be able to see that.My structure is like this:

httpdocs/site1 files  
and   site 2/site2 files

My guess is that both sites must be in httpdocs for this to work. Should I create folders site1 and site2 inside httdocs and move my sites' files in them? Will this mess up my site's functionality?

Comment: @thunder197 list out your file structure please?

Comment: Updated my question.Hope it helps you understand my structure (post formating is a little weird here).

Comment: So you're going to have to move your images folder to the root directory give it the correct permissions and change your file location options. They way you've set this up is awkward but doing that will work.

Comment: can you please be more specific on how to do that?

Comment: Kind of not really. I don't have enough information to give you specifics. In Drupal if you go to configuration media you'll see private and public folder that's where you can set which directory your images are in. But I can't tell you how to move your folders because I don't know what operating system your servers in and I can't tell you how to set the permissions because I don't know what tool you're using to access that server.

Comment: Server is running on Linux. I use Plesk to access my files, but i don't have access to server configuration files.I know how to change the public and private path through configuration.The problem is that it can't read from a path different than my desktop sites/default folder.

Comment: No one said anything about server configuration files. Can you read and write the root folder where httpdocs folder and mobile folder are?

Comment: Make a new folder at the root level called images. Move the files from httpdocs/site/default/files to the new folder change the location in Drupal to /images or ../images

Comment: I can read and write in both httpdocs and mobile folders.I can't find an option to change rights for the root folder though.I guess i can because it lets me create a folder.

Comment: Then your going to have to use @loganfarrs answers

Comment: Domain access requires some server configuration according to installation info.

Comment: If i create 2 folders in httpdocs and move all of my files in them, will this mess up my site?

Comment: Essentially you should be able to have /httpdocs/desktop /httpdocs/mobile and /httpdocs/images and point your urls at the desktop and mobile folders respectively have your images in the images folder

Comment: Now i have a structure like the one you said.Updated my question so you can see it.So i have a folder called images to the same level as my desktop and mobile sites and also copied all files from sites/default/files to my new folder. But when i set file system path as ../images it still can't display the images. What have i done wrong?

Comment: If i set the path to just /images it throws an error:  
"Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission denied in drupal_mkdir() (line 2413 of /var/www/vhosts/mysite/httpdocs/mysite/includes/file.inc).The directory /images does not exist and could not be created." I have given read and write permissions though, so i can't figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Tried it and it creates a folder inside desktop site folder, not to the same level as my desktop site folder.

Comment: Use ../images then

Comment: Then you need the full folder path. If that doesn't work you'll have to create a symbolic link between images folders for your two sites and hope that works. Please lookup creating. A symbolic link.